# What is the variable type for {"message":"ok"} in terraform

Tags: variables, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

I'm writing a terraform module for GCP uptime checks and I need to filter {"message":"ok"} in response body.

Need to pass **{"message":"ok"}** as a variable, but still cannot find the suitable variable type for it.

I tried complex variable types. But issue not resolved yet

Comment: What about a map? https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/types#map

Comment: There is no such type in terraform natively. However, you can define a variable of type map (like mentioned above) and use jsonencode built-in function to convert it to the format from the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a `map` as variable, example :

`variable.tf` file :

```
variable "message" {
  description = "Message"
  type = map
  default = {
    "message" = "ok"
  }
}
```

Display the message value in the `outputs.tf` file for example :

```
output "message_value" {
  value = var.message["message"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all This is resolved by using **jsonencode({ "message" : "ok" })**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).